# Google webfont subset sample strings

Tags: webfonts

I have written a WordPress plugin that allows any Google Webfont to be used in the CMS. It includes a font previewer that shows "The quick brown fox..." in each selected font. So far it has been used to request the latin (i.e. default) font only Google.

I have now extended the plugin to allow subsets to be requested for the selected fonts. There are a dozen Google Webfont subsets including, for example, latin-ext, greek and cyrillic.

Now the question: in the font preview page, I would like to show what these subsets look like. Are there any well-known or common unicode strings that will do this? I guess I am looking for the equivalent to "The quick brown fox" but for each of the Google subsets.

How the Google subsets map onto unicode named subsets, is not clear, so I may need to find something specific to Google.

Edit:

This is where the sample text is going to go. Maybe this is less exactly a programming problem and more about a source of data.

```
var settings = jQuery.extend({
    ...
    preview_text: {
        'latin': 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog',
        'latin-ext': '?',
        'greek': '?',
        'greek-ext': '?',
        'cyrillic': '?',
        'cyrillic-ext': '?'
    }
}, options);
```

If there is a way to programmatically get a selection of characters with glyphs unique to each subset, then I would be happy with that.

Comment: The strings will be going into a JavaScript object. Whether it is good practice to use Unicode characters in a JS source file, or if they need to be encoded in some ASCII format, I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just noticed that Google already provide some sample strings to use in its own font preview pages. The sample text is the same for the extended version as for the non-extended version of each subset that has an extended subset. I'll find a few additional characters for the extended subsets to complete my font preview.